# mongodb do a search that matches the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I need to do a query where it finds the users that match the elements of an array in the tag field, which is also an array

```
 const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']
 const users = await User.find ({tag: {$ in: arr}}). limit (10);
```

How do I show users that at least match at **least 3 items**?

Comment: i think its duplicate see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741093/find-elements-in-mongodb-that-contain-at-least-3-entries-in-an-array/68741325#68741325)